# how to get a panda column returning the minimum values between another column and a min_val

Tags: python, pandas

I whave a pandas dataframe and I would like to create a column that contains the minimum values between another column and a `min_val`. I created the simplified problem below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

min_val = 0.5

np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['col{0}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 5)])

df['col_4_min'] = df['col4'].apply(lambda x: min(x, min_val))

df
    col1   col2   col3   col4  col_4_min
0 0.7425 0.6302 0.5818 0.0204     0.0204
1 0.2100 0.5447 0.7691 0.2507     0.2507
2 0.2859 0.8524 0.9750 0.8849     0.5000
3 0.3595 0.5989 0.3548 0.3402     0.3402
4 0.1781 0.2377 0.0449 0.5054     0.5000
5 0.3763 0.5928 0.6299 0.1426     0.1426
6 0.9338 0.9464 0.6023 0.3878     0.3878
7 0.3632 0.2043 0.2768 0.2465     0.2465
8 0.1736 0.9666 0.9570 0.5980     0.5000
9 0.7313 0.3404 0.0921 0.4635     0.4635
```

Problem with this method is that I will perform the calculation on a dataframe containing an incredibly high number of rows, so the calculation needs to be fast (and therefore `apply` isn't really privileged in my case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) to compare a scalar (or array), with your col

```
In [94]:

min_val = 0.5
df['col_4_min'] = np.minimum(min_val, df['col4'].values)
df
Out[94]:
     col1    col2    col3    col4  col_4_min
0  0.7425  0.6302  0.5818  0.0204     0.0204
1  0.2100  0.5447  0.7691  0.2507     0.2507
2  0.2859  0.8524  0.9750  0.8849     0.5000
3  0.3595  0.5989  0.3548  0.3402     0.3402
4  0.1781  0.2377  0.0449  0.5054     0.5000
5  0.3763  0.5928  0.6299  0.1426     0.1426
6  0.9338  0.9464  0.6023  0.3878     0.3878
7  0.3632  0.2043  0.2768  0.2465     0.2465
8  0.1736  0.9666  0.9570  0.5980     0.5000
9  0.7313  0.3404  0.0921  0.4635     0.4635
```

Thanks to @Divakar that calling `df['col4'].values` will speed this up even more than using `clip`

Comment: this is actually faster for some reason

Comment: @StevenG the numpy methods will typically work on numpy arrays without any error handling, the pandas version have more built-in error handling which is why they are typically slower, additionally when the data is a numpy array it can just re-use this for the block array, for the other case it needs to allocate and copy the values

Comment: I understand, but still, assuming that your col is of dtype float, I would be fine with 10% slower, but the numpy approach is 2 time faster... that's just insane

Comment: @StevenG that still doesn't surprise me, the pandas method will be check the dtype, whether there are missing values, homogenous dtypes, etc. The numpy method just needs to make a boolean mask against the array and generate the numpy array with the appropriate values and these can be handled much faster by pandas with little overhead because of the numpy restrictions

Comment: Thank you both guys. @EdChum there is something I still don`t understand. I extended my problem to a min-max, so the clip method form pandas was performing well. However, I noticed a clip method under numpy. Testing for speed, both methods (pd.clip and np.clip) yield similar results for speed. Is it possible that the difference in speed between your answer (np.minimum) and @StevenG answer (pd.clip(upper)) is just due to the method itself?

Comment: There's probably some implementation detail as to why `np.clip` is the same speed as `pd.clip` which `np.minimum` doesn't need to care about

Comment: And some more speedup with the array data : `df['col4'].values`.

Comment: @Divakar that's true, have edited, will attribute also

Answer (score 4):

use clip()

```
df['col_4_min'] = df['col4'].clip(upper=0.5)
```